# In plant species' description, does the leaf length include the lamina and petiole, or only the lamina?

Tags: botany, species, morphology

The description (partially pasted below) of *Ramosmania rodriguesii* in Verdcourt (1996) states that the leaves are up to 30 cm long. Does this length include both the lamina and petiole, or only the lamina?

[image]

Reference (source of above paragraph):
Verdcourt, B. (1996). Ramosmania rodriguesii Rubiaceae. Curtis's Botanical Magazine, 13(4), 204-209.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=leaf+length+and+width&sxsrf=ALeKk03Q4CwiJUDmkRdlbh6NScJPyAzRYA:1607256593282&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5qriyqbntAhUS8uAKHbMNBbMQ_AUoAXoECBsQAw&biw=1572&bih=838#imgrc=2vp2ZJXmVhBuaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "Plant Identification Terminology: An Illustrated Glossary" (Harris & Harris, 2001) [my emphases added]:

- A **leaf** is "an expanded, usually photosynthetic *organ* of a plant."

  - A **lamina** is the "expanded portion" of a leaf.
- A **petiole** is a "leaf *stalk*" and a **stalk** is "the *supporting structure of an organ*, usually narrower in diameter than the organ."

I know you know the definitions here, but I'm using this as evidence that the petiole is often considered separate from the leaf itself.

I do not know of a flora, key, or guide that uses the petiole as part of the measurement.

Since Kew's [Plants of the World Online](http://powo.science.kew.org/taxon/urn:lsid:ipni.org:names:936959-1) lists this species as having 30 cm long leaves (and assuming they do not include the petiole as is common practice), I would assume your source likewise is not including the petiole.

Disclaimer: I have never seen *Ramosmania rodriguesii*, so I can't comment from personal experience/knowledge of this specific species. However, if typical measurement practices have been employed, I assume the petiole is excluded in leaf length measurements.

Answer (score 0):

**No** it doesn't [these days](https://www.google.com/search?q=leaf%20length%20and%20width&sxsrf=ALeKk03Q4CwiJUDmkRdlbh6NScJPyAzRYA:1607256593282&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5qriyqbntAhUS8uAKHbMNBbMQ_AUoAXoECBsQAw&biw=1572&bih=838#imgrc=2vp2ZJXmVhBuaM). That description of the leaf excludes the petiole length. 38 including both.

Comment: Hey FYI, your link doesn't work. Please fix and also consider both quoting from and formally citing the source to avoid issues of broken links. Thanks!